# Window background image triples the process memory usage

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Used to work with winforms, and recently started learning wpf.
For my main menu window, and a few selective windows, I'm using custom images for the Window Background

```
<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Views/1295.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
</Window.Background>
```

The image is only 760kb, but by simply running my application and loading the first window that only includes 5 buttons, it went from 100MB process memory when not using background image to 350MB when using.

How do i fix this or is there no way around it?
My winform application with similar layout only uses 30MB, is wpf supposed to be this big?

Comment: wpf apps tend to be fairly memory hungry. Is the background picture quality significant? You could try RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="LowQuality" If it's just to look pretty  you have the option to use various gradient brushes which can be in layers. And there are vector based shapes. A logo, for example, is often represented by a path with a geometry defining where it is. The parts of a geometry/path do not have to be contiguous. You can use inkscape to "trace" a bitmap into geometries.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the same picture multiple times, you can better declare it as a resource like this.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ImageBrush x:Key="imageBrush" ImageSource="/Views/1295.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then set the background-property to this resource.

```
<Button Content="Click me" Background="{DynamicResource imageBrush}"/>
```

Your process memory will still increase, but not by the same amount, because the image is just loaded once.

Comment: This is generally the right approach with resources in WPF, +1

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using each picture once for separate views, thnx!